# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of undefined on Rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I get the following error on each page of my Rails website when I'm clicking anywhere on the page:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of undefined

In the Chrome console, the bug appears on line 3 of this function (which is not mine) :

```js
$(document).on('click', 'body', function(e) {
  var tabs = $('#tabs');
  var width = Math.round(tabs[0].getBoundingClientRect().width);
  if (tabs.css('left') == '0px') {
    if (e.pageX > width && e.pageY > 60) {
      if (animationDone == true) {
        animationDone = false;
        tabs.animate({
          left: "-=" + width
        }, 400, function() {
          animationDone = true;
        });
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[image: The console error]

Do you have any idea what may be causing this bug? I commented all my JS which doesn't seem to cause this error.

Comment: `tabs[0]` is undefined, which would suggest that there is no `#tabs` element in the DOM when you run this code. To check this log `tabs.length` and check the output.

Comment: It was a gem called Arctic Admin which was causing this bug. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Bonapara Did you fix this ?